# Fetch api "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" response

Tags: javascript, react-native

Getting ("exception": "400 Bad Request: Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)", "message": "Invalid Input") as response.

```
var params = JSON.stringify(dummy_obj);

var userKey = 'apikey-123';

fetch(`someurl?key=${userKey}&`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    Accept: 'text/plain',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: {params},
})
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need {} for the params.

Comment: yes..Now its no more 400 bad request. Rather some invalid polygon exception

Comment: what's the exact error?

Comment: {"exception": "Invalid Polygon", 
  "message": "Invalid Input"}

Comment: try changing content type to 'application/text' instead of 'application/json'

Comment: after changing {
  "exception": "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable", 
  "message": "Invalid Input"
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`400 Bad Request` means the body of the request you're sending to the endpoint is invalid in some way. It reads as though the server is telling you that it threw an exception while attempting to parse the JSON you gave it. I would inspect your `params` and ensure it is valid.